# Is it necessary to use an 'if' statement here?

Tags: python, fluent

Example 6-3 of *Fluent Python* defines a private variable `self.__total` and uses an `if` statement prior to its assignment seen as below:

```
if not hasattr(self, '__total'):            
    self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)        
return self.__total
```

Why not just use the statement `return self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)` to make the assignment?

Comment: This seems a protection to compute only once, to not modify it OR for performance

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference, doing

```
return self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)
```

**will** overwrite any previous value private variable *total* holds, whereas,

```
if not hasattr(self, '__total'):            
    self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)        
return self.__total
```

will return the previous value if it was assigned before...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what you mean, but why not just letting the variable being overwrote everytime the class is called? Here is the codes:

Comment: You might not want to overwrite the value of total as it may contain some useful information which was computed before. Even if it doesn't, another good explanation is that you may not want to re-calculate the value of total again and again. In this case, it may seem unnecessary, but if you are doing some time-complex computation, you would want to return the former computed value rather than doing all that stuff again.